# how to subtract value from 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Using PHP I want to subtract 50 of column `coins` if have value > 50 , if not then subtract from 'e-coins' .

```
Users Table:

this is the sample 
id |user |coins |e-coins| 
1 |axxx |100 |100 | 
2 |bxxx |100 |0 | 
3 |cxxx |0 |100 |
and this is the result i want
1 |axxx |50 |100 | 
2 |bxxx |50 |0 | 
3 |cxxx |0 |50 |
```

PHP:

```
    $db->Query("UPDATE `users` SET `coins`=`coins`-'50' WHERE `id`='".$sit['user']."'");
```

value in column 'coins' could be 100 
and i column 'e-coins' could be 100

I want to subtract from column 'coins'  50 and leave e-coins as it is , but in case column 'coins' have less than 50 or not have any value so subtract from column 'e-coins' 
How can i do this ?

Comment: Use a `where` clause. Also you should parameterize your query. `UPDATE users SET coins = coins - 50 WHERE id = ? and coins > 50`

Comment: Oh, missed the second part. What if `ecoins` is less than 50, go negative?

Comment: What if the value is 40?

Comment: the minimum value is 50 . so it can't be 40

Comment: Your question is highly unclear and there is no expected output shown.

Comment: yes . 

value in column 'coins' could be 100 
and i column 'e-coins' could be 100 

i want to subtract from column 'coins'  50 and leave e-coins as it is , but i case column 'coins' have less than 50 or not have any value so subtract from column 'e-coins'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your colum coins data type is numeric

```
$db->Query("
    UPDATE `users` 
    SET `coins`= case when `coins` > 50 then  coins - 50  else coins end,
        `e-coins` = case when `coins` <= 50 then `e-coins` - 50  else `e-coins` end 

where  ....
```

could be you coins and e-coins column are not numeric so  try  cast as integer

```
  UPDATE users 
  SET coins= case when (CAST(coins) AS INT coins)  > 50 then coins - 50 else coins end,
   `e-coins` = case when(CAST(coins) AS INT coins)  <= 50 then `e-coins` - 50 else `e-coins` end 
   WHERE id= 'id'
```

seems that the use of coin in second case in direct update create some trouble so  i have tried using a inner join  with sublery for select  the case  and this houd work correctly

```
update users 
inner join (
 select  id, 
       case
        when  coins > 50 
          then coins - 50
          else coins
    end coins ,
    case
        when coins <= 50
        then `e-coins` - 50
        else `e-coins`
     end `e-coins` 
from users  ) t  ON t.id = users.id  
     and users.id = your_id_value 
set users.coins = t.coins,
    users.`e-coins` = t.`e-coins`
```

Comment: tried 

UPDATE `users` 
    SET `coins`= case when `coins` > 50 then  'coins' - 50  else 'coins' end,
        `e-coins` = case when `coins` <= 50 then `e-coins` - 50  else `e-coins` end 
  WHERE `id`= 'id'

but it subtract 50 from the 2 columns in same times , an i want to subtract 50 from only 1 column

Comment: @Dr.Mezo   but is not possible that in the same row coins is >50  and <= 50  so is not possibile that  the tow columns are updated  in the same row ..  which data type are the columns coins  and `e-coins` ????

Comment: for example the 2 columns i tested have 50 in each

so when i tried your answer it subtract from the both and the result was 0 in the 2 columns

Comment: the check is for one column >50 in this case is not = to 50 and can't update two column ..   which data type are the column coins and e-coins ?????? anyway answer updated  for string columns

Comment: type is Numeric "int(255)"

Comment: then  ..in the same row is not possible that a value is > 50 and in the same moment<=50 ..   .. is a logic issue  ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194549/discussion-between-dr-mezo-and-scaisedge).

Comment: @Dr.Mezo `int(255)` is quite big. Wouldn't `mediumint(7)` be enough? (the number in brackets is the digit count; 1000 = 4 digits.)

Comment: yes . 

value in column 'coins' could be 100 
and i column 'e-coins' could be 100 

i want to subtract from column 'coins'  50 and leave e-coins as it is , but i case column 'coins' have less than 50 or not have any value so subtract from column 'e-coins'

Comment: @Dr.Mezo  .. answer  updated .. with   (a working in y db test) solution  .. left me know

Comment: Now it works :) , Great Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use IF statement to implement this condition. For example

```
UPDATE `users` 
SET `coins` = IF(`coins` > 50, `coins` - 50, `coins`), 
    `e-coins` = IF(`coins` <= 50, `e-coins` - 50, `e-coins`) 
WHERE id = <your id>
```

Comment: if the 2 columns have value 50 .  it subtract 50 from the 2 columns in same times , an i want to subtract 50 from only 1 column